# Numpy array questions about .shape

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I'm new to numpy, and I have some troubles in array shapes.

I want to operate the array like a matrix in matlab. However, I'm confused about the following things:

```py
>>> b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])

>>> c = b[:,1] # I want c is a column vector
>>> c.shape
(2,)

>>> d = b[1,:] # I want d is a row vector
>>> d.shape
>>> (2,)
```

I want to treat `c` and `d` as column vector and row vector respectively.

I don't understand why `c` and `d` have the same shape `(2,)`.

So it troubles me in later calculations.

Could anyone help me deal with this problem. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a plain integer as an index returns that column/row as a true vector. This is similar to indexing a list - you only receive the element at that index. The containing dimension is stripped away:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> my_list[2]
'c'
```

Instead, you want a slice. A slice of a list is a (sub-) list, and a slice of a matrix is a matrix. With numpy, you can specify this either as slice notation using `:` or a sequence of indices:

```
>>> c = b[:,:1]  # slice notation
>>> c.shape
(2, 1)
>>> d = b[[1],:] # sequence of indices
>>> d.shape
(1, 2)
```

Slice notation is for consecutive index ranges. For example, `:1` means "everything from the start up to 1". Sequence notation is for non-consecutive index sets. For example, `[0, 2]` does skip index 1. If you just want a single index, sequence notation is simpler unless you are dealing with borders (first/last row/column).

Comment: It's very nice of you to answer my question. You explanation is clear, and I can learn much about how to get a row or a column vector.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you want your array `c` to be a column vector of shape `(2,1)`, you can reshape it by:

```
c = c.reshape(-1,1) # c.shape --> (2, 1)
```

Similarly, if you want your array `d` to be a row vector of shape `(1,2)`, you can reshape it by:

```
d = d.reshape(1,-1) # d.shape --> (1, 2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. This is a wonderful way to make the array become a row or column vector. Also it makes avoid the confusion where should I use a square brackets for index and where should I use just an index.

Comment: Indeed, this is the cleanest way to get row/column vectors. I am surprised it has not been the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Because I'm familiar with Matlab, I want use it like matlab. I think c[:,[1]] and d[[1],:] are more natural for me to know its shape. 
Anyhow, thanks for your help. If possible, I also want to give you a star.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
c = b[:,[1]]
d = b[[1],:]
```

to get the vector as an explicit row/column vector:

```
c.shape # (1, 2)
d.shape # (2, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question. Finally the program works well, but I'm still confused that why the index 1 must be in the square brackets, instead of just the index 1?